# static method patterns for constructor functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, static, design-patterns

```
function Foo(){...}
Foo.bar = function (){...};
```

Is this the only pattern for adding a static method to a constructor function?  In particular, is it not possible to create the static method bar() within the definition of Foo() itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you say "inside", it sounds like you need a clean way to keep everything in one place. You could potentially use a class inheritance library that has support for static declarations. Or simply take one and extend it yourself to add that capability.

For a simple (but not so compact) way to keep everything together, you could go with something like this:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    var ctor = function () {
        // the constructor
    };

    ctor.staticMethod = function () {
        // something static
    };

    return ctor;
})();
```

But! How important really is making the declaration self-evident that it is static? You could simply declare your static methods as prototype methods and convey the fact that they are static (i.e. not acting on the instance) methods with some code comments. There won't be any contractual enforcement of how these methods are invoked, but there will be few side-effects. So I would just go with:

```
function Foo() {
    // the constructor
    // optionally define instance methods here
}

Foo.prototype = {
    instanceMethod: function () {
        // some instance method
        // this.bar(); ...
    },
    staticMethod: function () {
        // some static method
        // return 2 + 3;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
// Using "prototype" explicitly can be your contract for saying "this is static"
var sum = Foo.prototype.staticMethod();

var inst = new Foo();

var sum2 = inst.staticMethod(); // You have the added benefit of being able to call your static methods on instances
```

I've found that the above comes in handy especially when you're using the factory design pattern. Your class can have some static factory methods in its prototype and you can invoke these factory methods even when you only have an instance whose origin class you don't know.

Comment: Why would `inst` have a method `sum` in your usage case? Wouldn't you need something like `sum.call(inst)`?

Comment: Also, on the "why not?" question - because it makes your code hard to read and reduces code compression.

Comment: `sum` is "static" in nature -- it doesn't really care about `this`. There is absolutely no need to use `call` in this case.

Comment: Right, but my point is that, unless I'm missing something, `inst` doesn't have a property named `sum` - it only has a property named `staticMethod`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @nrabinowitz "Hard to read" is subjective. It all depends on the conventions and contracts that you define. Remember, these classical inheritance, privates/publics/statics etc. are all non-JavaScript-native.

Comment: @nrabinowitz All Foo instances have the property `staticMethod` because it's in the prototype.

Comment: Point taken. Still, I think most Javascript programmers would find that an unfamiliar syntax.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But they don't have the property `sum`, which is what you're calling. I think this is just a typo, and I'm trying to help you fix it :).

Comment: Thanks.  This is really an academic question, I'm trying to understand the differences between adding/defining properties on a function object vs a regular object.  It seems a bit strange to me that you don't need to execute Foo() in order to add a property to the Foo object, but you can't do that same thing in the definition of Foo() (since the definition of Foo() causes a Foo object to be created).

Comment: @nrabinowitz I agree with you about the unfamiliarity bit! But my argument is that this convention could also be adopted.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ( function (fn) {
     fn.bar = function (...) { ... } ;
     ...
 } ) ( Foo.prototype ) ;
```

In other word, you create an anonymous function that will populate the prototype of Foo.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* create a static method within the constructor function, but only by using the same syntax:

```
function Foo(){
    Foo.bar = function (){...};
}
```

*But* this would only add the static method once the constructor is called. Also, it would re-add it every additional time the constructor is called, which seems wasteful, but I guess could be useful, e.g.:

```
function Foo() {
    var counter = (Foo.bar && Foo.bar() || 0) + 1;
    Foo.bar = function (){
        return counter;
    };
}

f = new Foo();
Foo.bar(); // 1
f2 = new Foo();
Foo.bar(); // 2
```

In this case, `bar` is updated to return the number of times `Foo` has been called - probably there's a reasonable variant here that could keep track of all instances in a useful way.

If you really didn't want to refer to `Foo` for some reason, you could be clever and do something like this:

```
var Foo = (function Private(){
    Private.bar = function (){...};
});
```

Again, this only works after `Foo` has been called at least once. Also, while this does demonstrate an alternative syntax, I'm having a really hard time imagining when you might want to use it.

Yet another variation here, probably equally useless:

```
function Foo() {
    this.constructor.bar = function (){
        console.log("test");
    };
}
```

Comment: Getting "TypeError: Foo.bar is not a function".

Comment: @osoviejo - yes, see my update - this only works after you've called the constructor at least once. There's **no** way to do something inside a constructor function that will take effect before the function runs.

Comment: There is nothing "static" about requiring a initial instance :(

Comment: @AtesGoral - well, not in the classical sense. But it's a standalone method attached directly to the constructor function, which is as close as Javascript gets to "static" anyway.

Comment: @nrabinowitz True true... But in any case, it is more natural to attach it outside the constructor, just like the OP has in their example. Perhaps the answer to the OP's question is a simple "no, that's the only way".

Comment: @AtesGoral - yup, I think so. I think this is a typical case of the OP saying *what* he wanted, but not why...